# Using autolayout constraints programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I'm trying to use autolayout in my iOS app programmatically.
I have a simple view controller with this init code

```c
UIView *innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 50)];
[button1 setTitle:@"button1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 50, 150, 50)];
[button2 setTitle:@"button2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[innerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[button1][button2(==button1)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button1, button2)]];

[innerView addSubview:button1];
[innerView addSubview:button2];
[self.view addSubview:innerView];
```

But when I'm trying to run this, I'm getting this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
|[button1][button2(==button1)]| 
          ^'
```

What's wrong with it?

And when I'm trying to remove pipes in `constraintsWithVisualFormat`, I'm getting this warning:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x716be10 h=--& v=--& UIRoundedRectButton:0x71631f0.midX == + 325>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7169940 h=--& v=--& H:[UIRoundedRectButton:0x715fb80(150)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7169860 h=--& v=--& UIRoundedRectButton:0x715fb80.midX == + 125>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7164cd0 UIRoundedRectButton:0x71631f0.width == UIRoundedRectButton:0x715fb80.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7164940 H:[UIRoundedRectButton:0x715fb80]-(0)-[UIRoundedRectButton:0x71631f0]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7164940 H:[UIRoundedRectButton:0x715fb80]-(0)-[UIRoundedRectButton:0x71631f0]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

And as result of this, my constraints have no effect at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have three problems:

First, you need to opt-in to layout based contraints on your both your button subviews

```
[button1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[button2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

This will get rid of the NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint errors. Now you can get onto what's going on with your layout constraints.

Second, you have to `addSubview` before adding the constraints. You are calling `addContraints` on innerView before button1 and button2 are subviews of innerview.

Third, you should specify (although the docs indicate it is optional) whether the layout string is vertical or horizontal. `@"H:|[button1][button2(==button1)]|"`. You will also want a vertical constraint like `@"V:[button1]|"` which would align button1 to the bottom of `innerview` and because you have aligned baselines on the buttons, button2 will follow.

Comment: Yep, `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` helped me to get rid of these errors. But as result I'm getting button2 aligned to the top-left corner (button1 is not visible), and yet I still cannot use pipes in `visualFormat`. Do you have any idea why does error says that `related view doesn't have a superview`. UIViewController's `self.view` is superview of my `innerView`, isn't it?

Comment: "related view doesn't have a superview" is because you're adding a constraint involving a view that hasn't been inserted into the view hierarchy yet. Move the addConstraints: call after all calls to addSubview:.

Comment: thank you, when I've moved code block with constraints under `addSubview` statements, error about 'unable to interpret pipe' was disappeared and I've got layout similar to what I wanted ) Thanks, the problem is solved )

Comment: Are there any additional considerations associated with adding the constraint after the subview has been added? Is there potential for a flicker as the constraints are resolved or does the iOS system handle this somehow behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record: the exception concerning the missing superview gets already triggered by `constraintsWithVisualFormat` not `addConstraints`