# UIView superview field not being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

So this is a strange one. I have a layout with a `UIVIew *` header element, a `UIButton *` footer element and a `UITableView *` element between them.

```
//each of these are instantiated in their own lazyload method
[self.view addSubview:self.headerView];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.view addSubview:self.footerButton];

NSDictionary * viewList= @{
                           @"header":self.headerView,
                           @"table":self.tableView,
                           @"footer":self.footerButton
                           };
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[header(40)][table][footer(50)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewList]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[header]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewList]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[table]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewList]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[footer]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewList]];
```

Now, the execution fails at the first addConstraints call, with this message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',     
reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
V:|[header(40)][table][footer(50)]| 
                                  ^'
```

All of my views have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `NO`.

The strange thing is that if I `NSLog` before adding the constraints I can see that `self.view.subviews` correctly lists all three views. However, `self.footerButton.superview` is somehow `nil` (the other two are fine).

How is it possible that a view is being added to the view hierarchy, but isn't setting its own superview?

Comment: Just a suggestion.. try printing your self.footerButton, i think it itself is nil.

Comment: Already thought of that. It is indeed an instantiated view with an output of `<UIButton: 0x78e7fbb0; frame = (0 0; 320 50); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e7fcb0>>`. It also prints the same data when listing `self.view.subviews`.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15346498/2713079. Hope this helps.

Comment: Already referred to that, but as I've noted, I have already verified that views are being added first, everything has `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` disabled, and the visual format syntax correct.

Comment: Did you log self.footerButton.superview to see that it returns nil, or are you assuming that based on the error message?

Comment: no i have logged each of the following:
`self.view.subviews`, `self.headerView`, `self.headerView.superview`, `self.tableView`, `self.tableView.superview`, `self.footerButton`, `self.footerButton.superview`

only the last one is nil.

Comment: It's hard to see how this could be possible. I would try removing all the code that refers to self.footerButton, and re-adding it to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I don't really see how this could be happening either.  Can we see where the button is loaded?   Also, did you try adding only the footerButton and confirming parentView was nil immediately after addSubview?  If not, try KVOing the parentView.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. the lazy-load getter for footerButton was accidentally returning the temporary view that was meant to be assigned to the ivar rather than return the ivar itself, so every call to `self.footerButton` was returning a new instance. As such, the first call WAS being properly assigned to the parent view, but when building the `viewList` it was a creating a new view that wasn't assigned to anything.

Comment: To be honest, a getter is not the best place to create data lazily. A getter that modifies data is breaking the contract. That's a bit different in Swift where `lazy` is a language feature.